# Unhandled Promise rejection NativeScript with Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have an Api.ts class, which handles all api calls and returns Observables that other components can subscribe to.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import config = require('./config');

@Injectable()
export class Api {
    private apiUrl: string = 'someUrl';

    constructor(private http: Http){
        this.apiUrl = config.apiUrl;
    }

    getSomething(url) {
        console.log(this.apiUrl+url);
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl+url)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    handleError(error: any) {
        let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
            error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg);
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
    }
}
```

Then another component has api.ts as a provider and wants to call it's method getSomething.

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';    
import {Api} from 'shared/api';

@Component({
    providers: [Api],
})

export class SomePage implements OnInit {

    constructor(private api: Api) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.api.getSoemthing().subscribe((res) => {
             console.log(res);
        });
    }
}
```

When I visit SomePage though I get

> JS: 200 -   JS: Unhandled Promise rejection: 200 -  ; Zone: angular ;
>   Task:Promise.then ; Value: 200 -    JS: Error: Uncaught (in promise):
>   200 -   JS: 200

I have checked [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38323438/what-could-cause-a-promise-to-fail-in-nativescript-angular2), it's solution doesn't help me though as I am already using NS_HTTP_PROVIDERS in my application's bootstrap.

I am sure it's something very trivial, but I cannot get the code to work.

Comment: Should you have `.catch(this.handleError());` rather than `.catch(this.handleError);` as your `.catch` callback?

Comment: I don't think this matters, they do the same in Angular2 tutorial on http calls anyway. I have now checked and constructor of Api doesn't even get called, so I think there is some component communication issue

Comment: OK, have you tried stepping through on a debugger and seeing where the error is thrown? Also, is the `.catch` event begin triggered? Maybe just put a `function(err){ consol.log(err) }` in the catch to test?

Comment: I've tried your solution, even removed the catch clause completely, still same error message, I suspect this service might be not injected properly